# How to perform self.view.frame.size.width using storyboard in iOS for Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, storyboard

I want set sub view's width same as super view's width. Programmatically using `self.view.frame.size.width` we can assign in `CGRectMake`.

But, how to do the same using storyboard? If it is possible using constraints then list steps for it.

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials online about how to use auto layout in storyboards. For instance http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2 . I'm voting to close as too broad.

Comment: please check edited answer.

Comment: You need to use yourView.layoutIfNeeded() and after that you will be able to assign the current super view size to your subViews instead of the storyboard view size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do same as in xib.
just create IBOutlet of subview. and give size regarding superview.
Ex,

I assume that you have created outlet of Subview with name subview1.

```
IBOutlet UIView *subview1;
```

and now set frame according to what you need.

```
subview1.frame=CGRectmake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
```

Thats it.

**Edit:**- Sorry i forgot to read that you have to set up it with constrain.

[image]